Passing providers to the next widget in a sequence
I have a list of widgets that need to be displayed in sequence, and I'm currently using a callback with a context push to initiate the display of the next widget.
The problem is that I haven't figured out how to correctly pass providers to the next widget.
In my code, first the callback is defined, then the list of widgets is created and the callback is passed into each of them, and then finally the first widget in the sequence is displayed.
This is the callback. What goes wrong is that the next widget can't find the provider using context.read inside didChangeDependencies.
void callback(int index, {Map<String, dynamic>? params}) {
      if (index >= widgetList.length - 1) {
        // no more widgets, pop all contexts
        Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst);
      } else {
        // find next widget to display
        Widget targetWidget = widgetList[index + 1];

        if (params != null && params.containsKey('providers')) {
          // prepare to pass providers to next widget
          final providers = params['providers'] as List<ChangeNotifier>;

          MultiProvider multiProvider = MultiProvider(
            providers: providers
                .map(
                    (provider) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: provider))
                .toList(),
            child: targetWidget,
          );

          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => multiProvider),
          );
        } else {
          // no providers to pass on, so just display the widget
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => targetWidget),
          );
        }
      }
    }


Why are you transferring to the provider? It is typically used globally to be able to process data from anywhere in the application. Declare the provider in a separate file and then import it to the desired location.
Usually the provider is announced above MyApp()
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counter()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}


I have to pass it with ChangeNotifierProvider.value because I’m pushing a new context, right? Providers are scoped so what’s defined outside of a context push won’t be available within it.

Make your provider static or simply create a new provider within a new context and access its data. Inside Widget build(BuildContext context)
